# A recursive version of a code

Tags: python

In determining if a string is a subsequence of another I have the following code:

```
def subseq(strA, strB):
    if not strA:
        return True
    else:
        for char in strB:
            if strA:
                strA = strA[char == strA[0]:]
    return strA == ""

>>> subseq('cat', 'XIKSLPWswifmscakst')
True
>>> subseq('cat', 'XIKSLPWswifmsctksa')
False
```

while this works fine, is there a way to solve this recursively?

Comment: Why don't you try and write a recursive version, then post when you're stuck.

Comment: Why is `'cat'` a subsequence of `'cakst'`?

Comment: Python provides `'cat' in 'LASJLFJD;lfasdcat'`

Comment: @JaredBurrows But wouldn't if "cat" in "catcat": check is cat is substring? While subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements without changing the order of the remaining elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterative versions usually works better on Python, since it doesn't have tail call optimization, and function calls are heavy. But as an exercise, here is my solution.

```
def subseq(needle, haystack):
    if not needle: return True
    if len(needle) > len(haystack): return False
    if needle[0] == haystack[0]: 
        return subseq(needle[1:], haystack[1:])
    else: 
        return subseq(needle, haystack[1:])
```

**But don't use this!**

- It'll cause stack overflow on long strings(`len(s) > sys.getrecursionlimit()`).
- It'll build a lot of intermediate strings(Every slice returns another copy)
- An iterative version is just as readable.

Comment: Right, but it isn't some kind of spoiler since he *asked* for it. And I had fun.